# What exactly is this rails 3 .build method doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Taking this snippet from the famous agile web development with rails book (most recent edition):

```
def create 

  @cart = current_cart 

  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
```

This is for a general ecommerce/depot app, and this function is for the "Add to cart" button for a specific product. Here's where I'm confused:

I imagined the code being:

```
@line_item = line_items.build(product: product) 

@line_item = line_items.build(cart: @cart)
```

Basically If a `line_item` belongs to both a product and a cart, I create those relationships separately.

Also, if the cart doesn't have any `line_items` yet, then how can I do `@cart.line_items`? I understand `line_items.build(product: product)` will return to me a `line_item` object (which I save into `@line_item`), but how does `cart.line_items` work if there's no `line_items` in the cart yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Cart` model, there is most likely a `has_many` association with the `LineItem` model called `line_items`. Rails will automatically initialize that association with an empty array.

You can think of `@cart` being initialized as:

```
@cart = Cart.new
@cart.line_items = []
```

Every time you add call `@cart.line_items.build`, think of it as this:

```
new_line_item = LineItem.new cart: @cart
@cart.line_items.push new_line_item
```

Note: This is absolutely not how the actual code works, but you can think of the functional behaviour as the same.

Answer (score 1):

@cart.line_items may behave like an array at times, but it is [actually an object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) with much more functionality that contains the relation information.  So when you call `@cart.line_items.build` you are actually sending a message `build` to an object of type (I think) ActiveRecord::Relation which then builds an object in memory of your line_item with the cart_id already set.